# New CentOS install login broken

Tags: centos, systemd, login

I've just finished installing CentOS on a fresh disk.  I did it in a slightly unconventional mannner - by running a complete `yum` install in a `chroot` from Debian.  So I had a few problems getting grub and `fstab` right.  But now I think I'm blocked.

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

The system starts up (all green OKs on the screen while booting), but I can't log in to a `tty` - when I type a username and password the screen refreshes with the username prompt.  I can log in to both accounts through a `chroot`, so that's not the problem.

Here's the (I think) relevant bit of `/var/log/messages`:

```
Sep 16 01:45:01 localhost systemd: Starting Multi-User System.
Sep 16 01:45:01 localhost systemd: Reached target Multi-User System.
Sep 16 01:45:01 localhost systemd: Starting Graphical Interface.
Sep 16 01:45:01 localhost systemd: Reached target Graphical Interface.
Sep 16 01:45:01 localhost systemd: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
Sep 16 01:45:01 localhost systemd: Starting Stop Read-Ahead Data Collection 10s After Completed Startup.
Sep 16 01:45:01 localhost systemd: Started Stop Read-Ahead Data Collection 10s After Completed Startup.
Sep 16 01:45:01 localhost systemd: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Sep 16 01:45:01 localhost systemd: Startup finished in 829ms (kernel) + 4.879s (initrd) + 23.991s (userspace) = 29.700s.
Sep 16 01:45:01 localhost NetworkManager[713]: <info>  startup complete
Sep 16 01:45:02 localhost systemd: SELinux policy denies access.
Sep 16 01:45:02 localhost systemd-logind: Failed to start unit user-42.slice: Access denied
Sep 16 01:45:02 localhost systemd-logind: Failed to start user slice: Access denied
Sep 16 01:45:02 localhost systemd-logind: Assertion 's->user->slice' failed at src/login/logind-session.c:515, function session_start_scope(). Aborting.
Sep 16 01:45:02 localhost abrt-hook-ccpp: Saved core dump of pid 609 (/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind) to /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2015-09-16-01:45:02-609 (614400 bytes)
```

The `backtrace` in the core dump is identical to [CentOS Bug: 8905](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=8905)

Next I'm going to add `SELinux=0` to the grub start script, but I don't want to do that permanently.
EDIT : I fixed it by adding `selinux=1 enforcing=0` to my grub boot parameters, then editing `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` and changing the state to `SELINUX=permissive`

I can log in and everything works now, but if I set SElinux back to enforcing, I can't log in at all.  Still looking for answers...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. Unconventional install as well, and I went with extlinux rather than grub. I tried logging in as root and as a regular user, neither worked.

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

I solved it by doing a complete SELinux relabel.

```
# inside the chroot from Debian
touch /.autorelabel
```

See [CentOS SELinux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-867ca18a09f3103705cdb04b7d2581b69cd74c55) for more details.